# ExoPlayer stuck at frame after Seeking, but Audio keeps playing in Background

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

So I have been working with ExoPlayer for streaming content in MP4 Dash File Format, and everything works fine, until I decide to change the Seekbar to a new position. On changing the Seekbar to a new position, the audio plays absolutely fine, but the video is stuck at a frame like a picture. Not sure why it's happening. Any help would be greatly helpful.

Edit:

```
PlayerView ep;
SimpleExoPlayer player;

boolean secondTouch=false;
boolean isPlaying=false;
boolean isLandscape=false;
long lastTimeTouched;

//ON SCREEN CONTROLS
LinearLayout mcContainer;
ImageButton ivPlay;
ImageButton ivSize;
TextView totalDuration;
RelativeLayout buffer;
SeekBar progress;
int totalTime;

Runnable runnable;

LinearLayout commentsContainer;

Intent i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    i=getIntent();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    details=findViewById(R.id.textView11);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);

    isLandscape=getResources().getConfiguration().orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;

    ep=findViewById(R.id.videoViewPlay);
    ivSize=findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    ep.setPlayer(player);

    mcContainer=findViewById(R.id.mcContainer);
    ivPlay=findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
    totalDuration=findViewById(R.id.textViewTotalDuration);
    buffer=findViewById(R.id.bufferContainer);
    progress=findViewById(R.id.seekBarProgress);

    ivPlay.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if(isPlaying)
        {
            player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            isPlaying=false;
            ivPlay.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        }
        else
        {
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            isPlaying=true;
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            ivPlay.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
        }
    });
    ep.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mcContainer.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = Tools.convertDpToPx(this,48);
        mcContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
        lastTimeTouched=System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(secondTouch==true){
            params = mcContainer.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = 0;
            mcContainer.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        secondTouch=!secondTouch;
    });

    progress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(fromUser) {
                player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                player.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeterA = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "eTuitionPro"), bandwidthMeterA);// This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
    String media=Uri.parse(Tools.baseAddress+"VIDEO/"+i.getStringExtra("ModuleID")+"/index.php").buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("token", Tools.token).build().toString();//NEEDS CHANGE
    MediaSource videoSource =new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(media));// Prepare the player with the source.
    player.prepare(videoSource);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    runnable = () -> {
        progress.setProgress(((int)(player.getCurrentPosition()/1000)));
        if(((int)(player.getCurrentPosition()/1000))==progress.getMax())
        {
            player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            isPlaying=false;
            ivPlay.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
            progress.setProgress(0);
        }
        else
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    };

    player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            switch(playbackState)
            {
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_READY:
                    totalTime = (int)(player.getDuration()/1000);
                    progress.setMax(totalTime);
                    totalDuration.setText(msToString(player.getDuration()));
                    buffer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
                    break;
                case ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING:
                    buffer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

        }
    });
...
```

In the above program I tried to make a custom Control Player UI for the ExoPlayer. Not sure if I did anything wrong, if there is a better way to do this, I will honoured to know more.

Comment: some code might be helpful

Comment: @Vucko Added the code you requested